# Application Insights API for custom metrics multiple dimensions

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer

I have the following code Application Insights API for custom events (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#get-a-telemetryclient-instance):

```
private void TrackResourceUnitsUsedByTypeEvent(int ruu, QueryType queryType)
{
        var ruuByTypeEvent = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "RunId", RunId.ToString() },
            { "ResourceUnitsUsed", ruu.ToString() },
            { "QueryType", queryType.ToString() }
        };
        _telemetryClient.TrackEvent("ResourceUnitsUsed", ruuByTypeEvent);
}
```

and the following kusto query:

```
customEvents
| where name == "ResourceUnitsUsed"
| order by timestamp desc
| project timestamp,
    QueryType = tostring(customDimensions["QueryType"]),
    ResourceUnitsUsed = toint(customDimensions["ResourceUnitsUsed"])
| summarize sum(ResourceUnitsUsed) by bin(timestamp, 1m), QueryType
```

How do I update the code to display custom metric instead of custom event?

Answer (score 0):

Just change `TrackEvent` to `TrackMetric`. With this you don't need to pass a value as custom property - instead you pass it directly. This simplifies (and makes it faster) Kusto query as well.

Here is how you can modify it:

```
private void TrackResourceUnitsUsedByTypeMetric(int ruu, QueryType queryType)
{
        var ruuByTypeProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "RunId", RunId.ToString() },
            { "QueryType", queryType.ToString() }
        };
        _telemetryClient.TrackMetric("ResourceUnitsUsed", ruu, ruuByTypeProperties);
}
```

And query:

```
customMetrics
| where name == "ResourceUnitsUsed"
| order by timestamp desc
| project timestamp,
    QueryType = tostring(customDimensions["QueryType"]),
    ResourceUnitsUsed = toint(value)
| summarize sum(ResourceUnitsUsed) by bin(timestamp, 1m), QueryType
```